# jpa select query on embedded elementcollection with criteria builder

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, predicate

I've got an entity with a embedded element collection like this:

```
...
       @Embedded
       @ElementCollection(targetClass = ProviderResponse.class)
       @JoinTable(
             name = "provider_response",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")
       )
       @AttributeOverrides({
             @AttributeOverride(name = "provider", column = @Column(name = "provider")),
             @AttributeOverride(name = "response", column = @Column(name = "response"))
       })
       @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
       public Set<ProviderResponse> getProviderResponses() {
          return providerResponses;
       }
...
```

I would like to write a Criteria using the JPA CriteriaBuilder framework so that when I pass it a `ProviderResponse` to compare with, it returns all entities that have that `ProviderResponse` in their `providerResponses` element collection.

`ProviderResponse` is simply a compound class of two enum classes, `Provider` and `Response`.

I'm trying to create a Predicate:

```
Predicate providerResponse = builder.equal(root.<Set<ProviderResponse>>get("providerResponses"), compProviderResponse);
```

This is not working saying that 
"Parameter value ProviderResonse did not match expected type [java.util.Set"

I understand this, but am unsure how do do the comparison that I want.

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

How embarrassing, I've just reflected a bit and found the answer.

The predicate should be:

```
Predicate providerResponsePredicate = builder.isMember(compProviderResponse, root.<Set<ProviderResponse>>get("providerResponses"));
```